# .htaccess password protection not working with domain on a folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have 2 domains mapped to the same server.
 - Domain-A is mapped to public_html directory
 - Domain-B is mapped to public_html/domainb directory

When I set a .htaccess user/password for directories that I access via the first domain (e.g. domain-a.com/wp-admin) everything works like a charm.

But when I try to set the same for directories that I access from the domain-b, I got a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error.

Below .htaccess code. Note that the very same code works on folders of the domain-a but not on domain-b:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "myuseradmin"
AuthUserFile "/home3/desempac/.htpasswds/public_html/domainb/wp-admin/passwd"
require valid-user
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

change the following line in your code accordingly :

```
AuthUserFile /path/to/password/file/.htpasswd
```

Make sure you located the .htpasswd file inside the folder that you want to protect it